# Plot multiple lines with sorted DataFrame fields by time stamp

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am looking for an elegant solution to plot lines via Plots.jl, sorted by time stamp

I want each line to represent closeAsk (Float64) data field by different year, judging by time stamp year i.e., 2002, 2003, etc.

So, if we have data stamp from 2002 through 2019 as the below example, we should have **18** lines on a graph.

```
julia> df2 = df[[:closeAsk, :time]]  
5000×2 DataFrame  
│ Row  │ closeAsk │ time                        │  
│      │ Float64  │ String                      │  
├──────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────┤  
│ 1    │ 0.9949   │ 2002-11-28T22:00:00.000000Z │  
│ 2    │ 0.995    │ 2002-11-30T22:00:00.000000Z │  
⋮  
│ 4998 │ 1.13414  │ 2019-02-06T22:00:00.000000Z │  
│ 4999 │ 1.13244  │ 2019-02-07T22:00:00.000000Z │  
│ 5000 │ 1.13251  │ 2019-02-10T22:00:00.000000Z │
```

The way I am thinking of is to use comprehension to create a set of DataFrames representing the closeAsk field for each year, which we feed to plot(x, y), where y is an array of those butchered DataFrames.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simplest to use StatsPlots.jl like this:

```
using StatsPlots, Dates
d = Date.(first.(df2.time, 10))
df2.year = year.(d)
df2.day = @. dayofyear(d) + ((!isleapyear(d)) & (month(d) > 2))
@df df2 plot(:day, :closeAsk, group=:year)
```

Note that I create `:day` in a way to align month-day combinations on x-axis correctly (controlling for the fact that in different years you might have a different collection of trading days and making a leap year correction where needed).

**EDIT**

Explanation of `@. dayofyear(d) + ((!isleapyear(d)) & (month(d) > 2))`:

1. `@.` broadcast all functions that follow this sign
2. `dayofyear(d)`: returns the number of day in a given year; note that leap years have 366 days and other years have 365 days
3. `((!isleapyear(d)) & (month(d) > 2))`: add 1 to a day number if the year is not a leap year and the date is past February, in this way we normalize all years to have 366 days (so that the same days in Month-Day format have the same day number - note that we have to shift by +1 dates starting from March, 1 till December, 31)

Here is a short example (note that 2020 is leap year and 2021 is not):

```
julia>  d = Date.(["2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-01"])
5-element Array{Date,1}:
 2020-02-28
 2020-02-29
 2020-03-01
 2021-02-28
 2021-03-01

julia> @. dayofyear(d) + ((!isleapyear(d)) & (month(d) > 2))
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 59
 60
 61
 59
 61
```

In this way for the same value on x-axis on your plot you always have the same day of year for all years.

Comment: I am going through your code in a moment, Bogumil. But, first I'd like to ask how you have nicely formatted my REPL output: I spent about 15 min manually inserting double spaces end of each line but couldn't do so for field name and type...

Comment: When you edit a post: 1) copy-paste your code to the editor; 2) highlight the code; 3) click `{}` button in the toolbar (it is called Code Sample) or press Ctrl-K. StackOverflow will then indent everything as needed.

Comment: Thanks again, Bogumil!

1) Nice work on "broadcasting" in creating 'd'. Can you 'dissect'  @. dayofyear(d) + ((!isleapyear(d)) & (month(d) > 2)) for me, please? I am not able to follow your logic here.

2) When I run the last line of command in REPL, somehow a graph doesn't get up on the Plot pane on my Atom IDE. I feel your code is legit and that we don't need the escape character ^(), as described on https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl. Any idea?

Comment: I will dissect it in the answer. Regarding plot not showing in Atom can you please check if it shows correctly in REPL from a console (in order to rule out that the problem lies on Atom side).

Comment: You do not need to use `^` escape as it is used to signal StatsPlots.jl that the symbol should be treated as is (and this is exactly what we do not want - we want it to be treated as column name). If you keep having problems can you post your data as a Gist so that I can run the code myself on it to test?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Julia and don't understand what you mean by "in REPL from a console." My understanding is REPL is same as Console - normally sitting at the bottom of Atom?

Comment: By console I mean Julia started from command prompt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) under Windows or terminal (press Ctrl-Alt-T) under Linux.

Comment: Another legendary moment, Bogmil! With my MX Linux, I get up an Xfce Terminal and type "Julia" to start REPL. The graph shows up indeed after your lines of code. So, yeah, an Atom problem, I can concur.